# External monitor very dim via laptop VGA

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, vga

I have an HP DV6 2115sa laptop running Windows 7, and have been using an external monitor (Samsung SyncMaster) using the VGA port. Having previously worked perfectly, it now suddenly seems to be an extremely dim display (only on external monitors), to the point where it looks black, but I can see the faint outline of text etc if I get very close.

**I have tried:**

- The monitor with other laptops, so it is not the monitor.
- Reinstalling/updating the graphics and monitor drivers
- Booting without a battery and reseating the RAM, as had been suggested elsewhere

Has anyone come across this before, or suggest anything else to try? Has my motherboard been knackered somehow? It is a couple of years old now and does have a tendency to overheat.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like the backlight in the screen has stopped working. But I've never heard of a case where it was dependent on the input. It's generally broken for all, or none.

Comment: well it kind of is broken for all, as it does the same with any monitor...it's almost like the full signal isn't being sent perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the monitor being broken for all. Backlighting isn't something generally controllable by the input source.

Comment: Which graphics drivers/chip does your laptop use? Some drivers have a UI for changing display settings aside from the Windows UI. There may be brightness or gamma settings that are turned way down low for external displays. Though you have re-installed the drivers it is possible that any personal settings were not removed. What about another monitor on the same laptop? VGA cables?

Comment: I will have a look at the settings tonight, other monitros display the same behaviour, the VGA cable is fine

Comment: It's ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 series.